# How to Trigger child method in ReactJS Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have some inline edit fields, clicking on save should trigger child method which executes the API call with other properties. Currently using useState to set the flag, but it is working only once, if I resubmit it is not working, instead I want to use the method.

Comment: Would `useImperativeHandle` fit your need?

Comment: Hello! Could you post your code (preferably a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so we can see what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to add an answer that works with useState repeatedly.  The trick is to use a ever-changing value instead of a boolean and take your action when the value changes:

```
function Parent() {
  const [signal, setSignal] = useState()

  const onClick = () => setSignal(Date.now()) // trigger the child to save

  return (
    <div>
      <Child signal={signal} />
      <button onClick={onClick}>Save</button>
    </div>
  }
}

function Child({signal}) {
  // send the data whenever signal changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (signal != null) {
      sendData()
    }
  }, [signal])

  return <div>...</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle):

> ## useImperativeHandle
>
> `js useImperativeHandle(ref, createHandle, [deps])`
>
> `useImperativeHandle` customizes the instance value that is exposed to
>   parent components when using `ref`. As always, imperative code using
>   refs should be avoided in most cases. `useImperativeHandle` should be
>   used with `forwardRef`:
>
> ```
> useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
>     focus: () => {
>       inputRef.current.focus();
>     }   }));   return <input ref={inputRef} ... />; }
>
> FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
> ```
>
> In this example, a parent component that renders `<FancyInput
>   ref={inputRef} />` would be able to call `inputRef.current.focus()`.

Comment: I new to ReactJS, I tried this , currently he child component also pick some selected data from the parent such as <SavePrefrence
    selectedCity={city}
    selectedState={state}
    selectedCountry={country}
/> having problem adding "ref" here as it complains ref is not a valid prop.

Comment: `ref` is assigned like a prop, but in the child you need to use `forwardRef` as shown.